# Streaming Server Desktop and Audio

Tags: javascript, php, html, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I want to show the desktop activities of the server with audio (from a mic connected to the server) in a clients browser.. I am totally new to this area. So first I studied PHP, HTML5 and JavaScript. But I still could not find a way to stream what I want.

Can someone suggest me a way to do this? Is this possible to do this?

I have already setup a local Apache server for testing purposes.

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: what desktop activity of the server ?

Comment: As an example screen of a application.. Say i am editing a document on the server using word. Then the word window will be displayed to the customer..

Comment: how about virtual desktop , vnc ?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion... But what i need is to use a browser and achieve.. As an example, a salesman operates the server and a customer is the client. And client needs to see the server desktop.. thats my scenario.. so i want to do this through a browser....

Comment: Google Hangouts, Screenhero...